# Is there a name for Goku Susano-like avatar?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super

Goku has a power that is being shown over a year ago (in 2020) which makes him capable of creating a giant energy form similar to Sasuke's Susano. He has since then used this power again.

Does this Goku Susano-like avatar have a name?